# A Russian string is displayed in the log.txt - this: ???? C# when used log4net

Tags: c#, webapi

I try to print russian string to log. used log4net.
this is my code:

1. A file where the messages are written in Web.config

   ```
   <configuration>
    <appSettings>
     <add key="logFilePath" value="~/logTest.log" />
    </appSettings>
   </configSections>


   <log4net>

   <appender name="RollingFileAppender" 
       type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\log.txt"/>
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="2MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>

       <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
       <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %level %logger 
          -  %message%newline%exception%newline------------------------- 
             ---------------------------------------"/>
       </layout>
     </appender>
     <root>
       <level value="WARN"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
     </root>
   </log4net>
   ```
2. the class Handles writing to the log and configurations:

   ```
    namespace Utils 
    {
     public class ClsLog
     {
      private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager
         .GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase
         .GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
      private static bool isInitialized  = false;  

      public static void WriteLog(enmLogType logType, string message)
      {
        Initialize();
        log.Debug(message);
      }


    private static void Initialize()
    {
        if (isInitialized)
            return;
        string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logFilePath"];
        string currentDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        currentDir = currentDir.Substring(6);
              currentDir += "\\..";

        FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(currentDir + "\\log4net.config");
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(finfo);

        log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy h =
       (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
        foreach (IAppender a in h.Root.Appenders)
        {
            if (a is FileAppender)
            {
                FileAppender fa = (FileAppender)a;
                // Programmatically set this to the desired location here
                if (path != null)
                {
                    string logFileLocation = path;
                    fa.File = logFileLocation;

                    fa.ActivateOptions();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        isInitialized = true;
    } 
   }
   }
   ```
3. print string in Russian:

   ```
   public void print()
   {
     Utils.ClsLog.WriteLog(enmLogType.Debug, "Русский");
   }
   ```

but the output in the file log is:

```
2023-01-16 12:52:17,282  DEBUG ???????
```

how I will get this result?:

```
2023-01-16 12:52:17,282  DEBUG Русский
```

and how I know what Encoding is used when file is created?

Comment: Are you sure the editor you are opening it with can display UTF-8?

Comment: Like @nvoigt said, what editor are you using? Notepad, WordPad or Word tend to assume an ANSI code page if the file doesn't have a BOM. Try Notepad++. It shows in the bottom right the used encoding for visualization (and can be changed by clicking on it).

Comment: i use in Notepad

Comment: The file was created with ansi encoding, not utf-8, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
 <encoding value="utf-8" />
```

Was hidden in the project. It should have been added to `log4net.Config`, and not in `Web.Config`.